# Java Web Start + Jogl + MacOSX + JDK1.7

Tags: java, macos, jogl

**I have a project using Jogl 1.0 library http://easystoneshop.com/applets/CountertopQuote/index.html. My application start as Java Web Start.  All work allright, but on Mac Os X 10.7.5 whith update JDK 1.7.0.51 my project don't work. Exeption:**

JNLPClassLoader: Finding library libjogl.dylib
exception in QueueFlusher:
javax.media.opengl.GLException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.java2d.opengl.CGLSurfaceData.createCGLContextOnSurface(Lsun/java2d/opengl/CGLSurfaceData;J)J
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.Java2D.createOGLContextOnSurface(Java2D.java:470)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXJava2DGLContext.create(MacOSXJava2DGLContext.java:116)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXJava2DGLContext.makeCurrentImpl(MacOSXJava2DGLContext.java:72)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:182)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLJPanel$2.run(GLJPanel.java:650)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.OGLRenderQueue$QueueFlusher.run(OGLRenderQueue.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.java2d.opengl.CGLSurfaceData.createCGLContextOnSurface(Lsun/java2d/opengl/CGLSurfaceData;J)J
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLSurfaceData.createCGLContextOnSurface(Native Method)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLSurfaceData.createOGLContextOnSurface(CGLSurfaceData.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.Java2D.createOGLContextOnSurface(Java2D.java:468)
    ... 6 more

**I try run project on  Mac Os X 10.7.5 whith JDK 1.6.0.37 and all worked.**

I add native library file libjogl.jnilib on JRE Library and as Application all worked on Mac whith JDK 1.7. 
I try update Jogl to version 2.2 but have many Exeption:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Exception @ destroy's associateDrawable(false)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.destroy(GLContextImpl.java:447)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$OffscreenBackend.destroy(GLJPanel.java:1518)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$6.run(GLJPanel.java:1248)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:193)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.dispose(GLJPanel.java:463)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.removeNotify(GLJPanel.java:568)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel.destroy(GLJPanel.java:486)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel$2.run(GLJPanel.java:282)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.awt.AWTWindowClosingProtocol$WindowClosingAdapter.windowClosing(AWTWindowClosingProtocol.java:71)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2051)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:296)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: javax.media.opengl.GLException: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glFramebufferRenderbuffer( 0x8D40,  0x8CE0,  0x8D41,  0x0): GL_INVALID_OPERATION ( 1282 0x502), 
    at javax.media.opengl.DebugGL4bc.writeGLError(DebugGL4bc.java:29490)
    at javax.media.opengl.DebugGL4bc.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(DebugGL4bc.java:12353)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.detachColorbufferImpl(FBObject.java:1570)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.detachAllImpl(FBObject.java:1870)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.FBObject.destroy(FBObject.java:1911)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLFBODrawableImpl.initialize(GLFBODrawableImpl.java:163)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLFBODrawableImpl.associateContext(GLFBODrawableImpl.java:347)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.associateDrawable(GLContextImpl.java:733)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.destroy(GLContextImpl.java:412)
    ... 33 more

**I understand that the problem can be solved very simple, but I'm already the second week I'll bet on it. Help me please.**

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 Update 51 came with some new security changes for Web Start and applets.  [See this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html) for more detailed info.   A couple of the things are:

- You need to sign the applet with a valid certificate, not self-signed cert.
- You need to change the jar to include some new attributes to the MANIFEST.MF
- You may also need to update the  tag to include a permissions attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The maintenance of JOGL 1 has been stopped in 2010, you must switch to JOGL 2 (currently 2.1.4). As there have been some changes in the public APIs, you'll have to modify your application (some packages have been moved, you'll have to use a GLProfile, the buffer utilities are now in the class Buffers, ...). I advise you to contact the JogAmp maintainers if you suspect a bug in GLJPanel and you'll have to follow mikemil's advises for your own JARs.